# In spoken English, can we reply "I think so" to an interrogative sentence?

Tags: speech, yes-no, answers

In spoken English, is replying with "I think so" an acceptable way to reply to an interrogative?

> Q: Has anyone seen my torch?
> A: I think so. / I don’t think so.

Or it is better to reply with a *yes* or *no*, such as:

> Q: Has anyone seen my torch?
> A: Yeah, I think so. / No, I don’t think so.

Comment: What an odd question to answer so hesitatingly. Whether you add the initial _yes/no_, surely you **know** whether you’ve seen person A’s torch or not.

Comment: If it's a Yes/No question. _I think so_ means 'Yes, to whatever the question is'; _I don't think so_ means 'No', in the same circumstances. But you can't do it with a _Wh_-question like _Where have you left Dr. Armbruster?_

Comment: The hesitance could be for any reason, for example, "I saw a torch, it might be yours..."

Comment: @DJFar hesitation, in English.

Comment: This has nothing to do with grammar; it's about helpfulness.

Comment: @Lambie, *hesitance* is an English word, and it differs slightly in meaning to *hesitation*. Hesitance implies a certain reluctance or reticence to proceed, where hesitation means pause.

Comment: @DJFar Just because a word is in the dictionary...but I don't see how we can say there is either of those in the quoted speech.

Comment: @Lambie I was responding to the comment above by Janus. Please read for context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can (quoth Obama).

Even though I would guess nearly everyone automatically adds in the *yeah/no* at the beginning, you don’t actually need it if you don’t want it there. The answer is perfectly fine without it.

In casual speech, we tend to start off with a yes or no when answering a yes/no question quite by reflex, as evidenced by the game where you’re not allowed to say the words *yes* and *no* (or variations thereof)—it’s extremely difficult to keep up, because we say those two words so naturally and instinctively that we simply *can’t* not say them.

When writing dialogue in a story, for example, we are not constrained by this, and an answer like “I (don’t) think so” is perfectly natural without the initial affirmation/negation:

> A: Has Charlie left already?
>   B: I think so. He said something about leaving the oven on …

Comment: Excellent discussion. I especially like the final example, in which the response "I think so" doesn't mean "Yes" so much as "I'm not sure, but I consider it more probable than not."

Answer (score 0):

> can we reply “I think so” to an interrogative sentence?

[I think so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony).

Comment: While I appreciate the intent behind this post, it kind of kicks itself in the ear here—once you click the link, you start wondering whether the answer is actually saying ‘yes’ or ‘no’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- [Look deeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception#Ending).